# calculate density of multivariate normal distribution manually

Tags: r, function, normal-distribution, probability-density

I want to calculate the density of a multivariate normal distribution manually. As inputs of my function, I have `x` which is a `n*p` matrix of data points, a vector `mu` with `n` means and a covariance matrix `sigma` of dim `p*p`.

I wrote the following function for this:

```
`dmnorm <- function(mu, sigma, x){
k <- ncol(sigma)
x <- t(x)
dmn <- exp((-1/2)*t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x- 
mu))/sqrt(((2*pi)^k)*det(sigma))  
return(dmn)
}`
```

My own function gives me a matrix of `n*n`. However, I should get a vector of length `n`.

In the end, I want the same results as I get from using the `dmvnorm()` function from the `mvtnorm` package. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x- 
mu)` is p x p, so that's why your result is that size.  You want the diagonal of that matrix, which you can get using

```
diag(t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x-mu))
```

so the full function should be

```
dmnorm <- function(mu, sigma, x){
  k <- ncol(sigma)
  x <- t(x)
  dmn <- exp((-1/2)*diag(t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x- 
    mu)))/sqrt(((2*pi)^k)*det(sigma))  
  dmn
}
```